# Yii2 not found folder vendor?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, vendor

Installed yii2, after checking did not find the folder 'vendor'.
Everything was done, as written in the instructions on the site yii2.

How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `composer update` command in project directory (for example, `/var/www/yourprojectname/` or in Windows `C:/wamp/www/yourprojectname`.